# How to disable sound in notification (Notification in Android O or above)

Tags: android

My app requirement is to update the a media style notification upon player state change. Work perfectly before, fires and shows a new  media type notification with the mediaSession **without sound or vibration.**

**Problem now:** In building a notification channel per Android O requirement, I use the following code to create the notification channel. Then the annoying problem is, every time the media session changes, each notification updates, in Android O now plays a notification sound.

I would like to disable the sound for each new notification, if I don't set a sound, the default sound fires, passing in null in both field doesn't work.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                "SimpleBakingApp Media Notification",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationChannel.setSound(null,null); // <-- Is there a way to disable sound? null doesn't work
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
```

**Extra info, may be relevent**

my showNotification() (The method that builds the notification) fires upon player state changes in the Player.EventListener callback, I'm using ExoPlayer v2.

Answer (score 11):

What you're looking for is [`setOnlyAlertOnce(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOnlyAlertOnce(boolean)).

When you're creating your notification, you can set this to `true` if you only want the first display of that notification (and not subsequent updates to the same notification) to trigger sound and/or vibration.

Comment: Thanks ! That solves the 99% of the problem, but what I want is no sound or vibration at all, I dealt with the vibration with setting enableVibration() to false(). Still need a solution for the sound though.

Comment: Unfortunately, with notification channels that's out of your hands after you've created the channel. Once created, you cannot modify those properties after the fact. You could create an additional channel for these silent notifications, and do not call setSound() on that channel. You may also have to set it to IMPORTANCE_LOW.

Comment: Thanks, I've set the IMPORTANCE_LOW but didn't reinstall the app on the testing device. Now I reinstalled the app and the sound is gone, thanks.

Comment: Reinstalling the app worked for me either